# Switch layouts of CWnd inside CVIew

Tags: mfc, mdi, splitter, tabbed-view, cview

I have MDI application with Document/View enabled.
Inside CView class of the application there are created several CWnd derived child windows(different views) and then placed inside tab control (CMFCTabCtrl), which is also created in application CView class. So, I can see tabs inside each application document and by switching between these tabs, see each child view. For example, one view with OpenGL data visualization, another with text editor window, third with table visualization and so on.

Now, I want to add possibility to see all created child views simultaneously, separated with split control inside one document and switch between this new layout to tabbed layout, mentioned above, and vice versa by menu command.
So, I wonder what is the best way to accomplish my task

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The SWSPLIT sample app on MSDN does just about everything that can be done with views and splitters.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199515/en-us

Comment: Thank you for provided article. Unfortunately I cannot download SwSplit.exe form that link. It seems that the file is removed. Also, I couldn't find any links where I can download this sample. Is there any alternate source, which I can use?